# ASPX Literal Control Caching?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, sitecore, ascx

Im adding a literal control to my ascx page

```
<asp:Literal ID="customLiteral" runat="server" />
```

Inside the Page_Load method I'm populating this text dynamically using the httpContext. I need to read some cookies to set the value of this Literal.

```
customLiteral.Text = Utility.RenderText(HttpContext.Current) + "<h3>" + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + "</h3>";
```

This works perfectly fine on the first load of the page. But does not hit my RenderText method on subsequent loads, so does not honor the value of cookies to render this literal. I added in the date value for testing and the value also remains a constant. Would the literal value be cached somehow? I'm also hitting the breakpoints inside my Page_Load only once on the first load. Is there a better way to achieve what I want here?

Comment: What is Utility? It's unlikely the literal is caching. However you can test this with the following: customLiteral.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();

Comment: That is one of my custom function, that is doing some custom business logic to read cookies and return a string. I will try your Date approach. Good Idea. Thank you

Comment: It's not clear whether the literal or the custom code is preforming the caching? I would suggest; test the literally with DateTime. If it's the custom code, then show a re- producible example.

Comment: I added the date and also updated my question. The date value is also not changing after first load

Comment: Can you upload the code to re-produce this issue? I'm assume Page_Load does not contain any code that interferes with assign data to literal, E.g IsPostBack? Also the question is tagged with Sitecore. Could this be preforming the caching?If not there may be some sort of caching service in web.config? Also you can create an empty web form page and add a literal that assigns a DateTime. - this test if there is caching by default.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your series of interactions with Greg, I suspect that some form of output caching is occurring. If so, there are handful of ways to get whatever data you're trying to have presented in real-time and on each load to show up on page refresh.

The key to implementation comes in the form of something called **post-cache substitution** (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms227429(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) This technique is also known as "donut caching" because when you think about a donut, there's a hole that's cut in the middle. To compare: if your HTML page output were the donut, the "hole" in the middle of it would be the location where you want to place your output (your Literal control) on-demand each time the page is served and not just rendered in the page lifecycle.

Post-cache substitution can be done entirely within code, but I've preferred to use the Substitution control (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.substitution?view=netframework-4.8) as it makes things a little easier to understand. This control consists of two logically separate parts. There's the section that responds within the normal ASP.NET page/control lifecycle (e.g., Page_Load). The other portion is a public static method that gets called on the control just before the served back to a user from the output cache. That static method is where you might serve up the contents of what you're currently attempting to show with your Literal control.

I present at conferences and events on caching a lot, and I developed a sequence diagram to help my audiences understand what's going on:

[image]

I normally work with SharePoint, and I've implemented this in numerous scenarios to great effect. I hope it works for you!

Comment: Thank you Sean. This is really detailed and useful information! I tried using a Substitution control, but it is rendering outside of my ascx component root on the first load and not loading it on subsequent loads. Seems like it is not respecting the position in the ascx file where I added the Substitution control

Comment: Given your results, @ManojSreekumar, I'm also inclined to think that there's more in play. Greg suggested the possibility that Sitecore could be involved. Any thoughts on that?

I have seen one particular case produce improper generation of a Substitution control, and that's when page-level rendering has been overridden by a custom master page. In those instances, the Substitution content was emitted at the beginning of the HTML stream rather than in it.

Without additional information, I'm not sure what else to suggest. I'd look carefully at the end-to-end process for insight.